# jQuery to give specific tags CSS

Tags: jquery, this, attr

I'm trying to read the href of a pair of links, and depending on what the href is, I want to give the specifik link some CSS. This is the code I've tried:

```
$('.pane-menu-block-2 .menu li a').each(function(){
if($('a[href="node/3"]')){ $(this).attr('style','background-image:url(/sites/all/themes/zen/zen-internals/images/fraga_lararen.png)'); }
})
```

but it won't work. It gives the same background to every link in that div. The links looks like this:

```
<div class="pane-menu-block-2">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Våra program</a></li>
        <li><a href="node/3">Fråga läraren</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if($('a[href="node/3"]'))` will always come into the if block, because in javascript, an object is always be considered as `true`.

You should check the href like below:

```
$('.pane-menu-block-2 .menu li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') === 'node/3') { 
        $(this).attr('style','background-image:url(/sites/all/themes/zen/zen-internals/images/fraga_lararen.png)'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't work as `this.href` returns the full URL including the domain name.

Comment: Can I change this to check for the value inside <a>value</a>?

Comment: @DanielLundahl Yes, use `$(this).text()`

Comment: I tried to change if($(this).attr('href').... to if($(this).text('Våra program')... but that changed all values to 'Våra program'. x)

Comment: Aaah, it has to be $(this).text() === 'Våra program'!! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.pane-menu-block-2 .menu li a').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).attr('href')==='node/3' ) { 
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/sites/all/themes/zen/zen-internals/images/fraga_lararen.png)'); 
    }
})​;​
```

Or simply do it with the selector, no `each()` function needed :

```
$('.pane-menu-block-2 .menu li a[href="node/3"]').css('background-image', 'url(/sites/all/themes/zen/zen-internals/images/spank_the_teacher.png)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), you can match the current element against a selector. The big mistake you make in your code is that you're selecting every `<a>` in the document, instead of using `$(this)` which references the current element in each iteration of the `.each()` loop.

```
$('.pane-menu-block-2 .menu li a').each(function() {
    if($(this).is('a[href="node/3"]')) { 
        $(this).attr('style','background-image:url(/sites/all/themes/zen/zen-internals/images/fraga_lararen.png)'); 
    }
});
```

You could also go simpler and use a standard equality (`===` to strictly type it):

```
if($(this).attr('href') === "node/3") { 
    $(this).attr('style','background-image:url(/sites/all/themes/zen/zen-internals/images/fraga_lararen.png)'); 
}
```